# when creating custom map in Highcharts I want to use a background image however the custom map scales differently

Tags: dictionary, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnd0R.png)Per this page (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps) I open inkscape, insert an image I want to draw over and then click on "resize page to selected object" with the image selected.  This resizes the page to the size of my background image.  I then create the shapes over the image as instructed in the page referenced above.  What I want to do is when I paste the svg into the highcharts converter it keeps the shapes as drawn on the page so that I can then insert that same picture into the background of my highchart map on the page and the shapes I have drawn fit perfectly where I drew them on the image in inkscape.  Instead it seems like the converter resizes the shapes to best fit the screen.  If I didn't want the background image then this would be perfect however with this feature all the images drawn no longer "fit" in the background image where I drew them.  Any way to get this to be a 1:1 size conversion so that inserting a background image works?

Comment: Please add a live demo of what you have already tried. Minimal demo will be best. Please also add SVG code used in the [map from SVG converted](https://www.highcharts.com/studies/map-from-svg.htm).

Comment: Kacper - ok first I went into mspaint and for a simple example made a pic with a circle and a square.  Then I opened inkscape and click/dragged the mspaint file into inkscape and hit ok.  Then I clicked on the image - went to edit - resize page to selection.  So that after that the inkscape space was just the image with the square and circle.  Then I drew a circle and a square just as the highcharts how to page said to do.  Then I saved the inkscape file, opened it with notepad++ and used that on the highcharts conversion page.

Comment: I think here is where the issue is starting as when you open the inkscape converter page and put the info in, the size of the square and circle I drew are not the same size/location as when I drew them in inkscape.  The converter seems like it zooms in on them to best fit them.  
Then I opened the highcharts map and set the background image to be my original image of the circle and square I created in mspaint and now the square and circle created by the highcharts conversion no longer line up with the original drawing - they are bigger.  I am going to try to post pics of this here now.

Comment: I inserted the image into my original post above

Comment: here is what comes out of the converter.  It does seem to "zoom in" on what you have drawn which is good for displaying the shapes but I think this makes it impossible to then overlay it over the original image.

Comment: [
 {
  "type": "map",
  "data": [
   {
    "name": "path21",
    "path": "M577,-161,986,-168,1000,286,570,279z"
   },
   {
    "name": "path23",
    "path": "M158,-390,0,-515,82,-685,241,-688L331,-591,315,-464,194,-399z"
   }
  ]
 }
]

Comment: Here's a live demo with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y3mogx92/ You could set xAxis and yAxis min and max to change position of draw elements (zoom in or out) or you could set chart's margins to adjust position of the drawings. In general Highmaps are designed for maps and the feature with matching background image is not implemented.